# Finding a invariant subspaces for a specific matrix, but this time: over C

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, algorithms, invariant-subspace

[The matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qIdU.png)

I found a good algorithm here, ( [Finding a invariant subspaces for a specific matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31158/finding-a-invariant-subspaces-for-a-specific-matrix) )

but this time I want to find the invariant subspaces for a specific matrix **OVER C** (complex).

does it matter?
thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The approach would be the same, if your matrix were diagonalizable. However, the matrix is not diagonalizable; we're missing an eigenvector for $\lambda = 2$.

Comment: The space spanned by the first two columns is invariant.